# How to dynamically populate info.plist for 3D touch app shortcut

Tags: ios, iphone

in iOS9 if you look at the app phone or message when you make a deep press on the app icon you have a shortcut menu appearing containing custom dynamic choices such as the last person or the favorite person to contact. But they say we should put all the information regarding those shortcut in the info.plist thus I am wondering how can they populate the info.plist with changing informations.

Comment: Have you read the documentation ? - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationShortcutItem_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016501

Comment: Nice, I did not find this doc before but I looked. Exactly what I needed!